# HapiJS v18: returning a zip file / stream

Tags: zip, hapi.js

I have an endpoint on my Hapi server which builds a (sometimes) large zip file.

I want to return that file back to the frontend, but I can't seem to figure out how to make that work in the current (18) version of Hapi. There were some MAJOR api changes recently and all the examples I can find are completely out of date.

Some code that writes a test zip is below:

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
      let zip = new JSZip();
      zip.file('test.txt', 'derp derp');
      let stream = zip.generateNodeStream({streamFiles:true})
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.zip'))
        .on('finish', function () {
            // JSZip generates a readable stream with a "end" event,
            // but is piped here in a writable stream which emits a "finish" event.
            console.log("out.zip written.");
        });
```

but I cant seem to figure out what to do after.  I have tried all of the following so far:

```
// vanilla hapi
return zip;

// from Inert:
return h.file(zip);

// from Toys
return Toys.stream(zip);

// vanilla Hapi, take 2:
return h.reply(zip).type('application/zip');
```

But no luck.  Ideally I'd like it to stream as the file is being built, which I have seen examples of people doing, but they were all either an outdated version of Hapi or another framework altogether.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @MonkRocker, Have you found a solution to your problem? Can you give the correct answer.